# how to get value of an input box in html and do operations on it

Tags: javascript, html

I was testing a simple code to:

1. Get value of an input box
2. Do Mathematical operations on it...

My Code:

```
setInterval(function(){var a=document.getElementById("myInputBox").value;var b=a+1;a.value=b;},1000);
```

I am trying to add `1` to the value of that input box, every 1 second.

For example, if the box has value `1` ,then after 1 second it should become `2`,....and so on.....

But it gets joined with the box's value, like `11` instead of `2`.

Why is that?

Comment: Values in `input`s are always strings, you've to convert them to numbers before doing math.

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = parseInt(a) + 1;
```

`a` is a string, so the `+` is interpreted as string concatenation by default. To fix, pass `a` to `parseInt` because it returns a type integer. Now the `+` becomes a math operator.

*Extra Credit:*

```
var b = parseInt(a, 10) + 1;
```

For an extra measure of integrity, pass the second (*radix*) argument, ensuring *base 10* is used to determine the return integer value.

Answer (score 2):

**Try with full code & demo:**

get value from inputbox is a string, so it can't calculate mathematically. so, at first convert string to numeric by using function `parseInt` and then calculate and put into box.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("myInputBox");
  var r = parseInt(box.value, 10) + 1;
  box.value = r;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInputBox" value="1" />
```